# How to adjust plots in a for-loop

Tags: for-loop, matplotlib

I created a for-loop that generates a new image every increment. I'm just wondering how I could adjust the images within the loop. Right now, it is just plotting images in a single column. How can I adjust the images in the for-loop so it shows two columns?

```
for i in range(10):
            a = (0 + i, 0, 0, 0)
            plt.imshow(a)
            plt.title("Hi " + str(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`matplotlib.pyplot.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) you can create a single *figure* containing a *2D grid* of smaller plots (or *axes*, as they are called in Matplotlib), next you can iterate on the 2D structure as usual (just remember to call the `.tight_layout` method to narrow the plot frames and have enough space for the labels).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                   

fig, grid = plt.subplots(5,2)                                                     
count = 1                                                                         

for row in grid: 
    for ax in row: 
        ax.plot((0,1),(count,count)) 
        count += 1 

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]